# How to check if PHP associative arrays are equal, ignoring key ordering?

Tags: php, associative-array, json

Say I have two complex nested arrays in PHP, like these:

```
$a = array(
    "x" => array(4, 5, 6),
    "y" => array("z" => "foo", "q" => "bar")
    );
$b = array(
    "y" => array("q" => "bar", "z" => "foo"), 
    "x" => array(4, 5, 6)
    );
```

(In this case, they're decoded JSON data from different sources).  Assume the contents can be arbitrarily nested, but will not contain any circular references.

What's the most straightforward way to check if they are equal, ignoring key ordering?  For example, the above two should compare equal.  However, if `$b["x"]` were `array(4, 6, 5)` they would not be.

I could recursively `ksort` and compare the results, but I don't really want to modify either operand, and this seems like something that might have a simple one-line solution I don't know about.  Is there anything out there?

Comment: copy the array, sort it and compare. That way, you still have the original

Comment: Yeah - it's those "default" numeric indexes that will get you.  Otherwise, `$a == $b` would work fine without concern for order.

Comment: $a == $b is actually false in the above case, because the x and y keys are reversed, and the z and q keys are reversed inside of y.

Comment: @Walter Mundt: `$a == $b` is actually true in your above first example because order is not factored in for this type of non-strict comparison between arrays, not even in nested arrays.  Basically, if key exists in both arrays and the value is the same, it's at least loosely equal.  Throwing in `array(4, 6, 5)` to the mix would mean it would no longer loosely equal `array(4, 5, 6)` because numerical index=>value is now completely different between the arrays.  If you did `$a === $b`, then yes, because array ordering is now strictly checked, it would be false anyway.

Comment: @Walter Mundt: I'm referring to this comparison behavior: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: Also, array comparisons are done recursively, which is why `$a == $b` checks out no matter how out of order the nested arrays are initialized as long as `$a['x'][0] == $b['x'][0]`, etc.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, the types DO matter to me, so == is not really useful, because I need to distinguish 0 from "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing this, is already mentioned by you. But you forgot 1 thing.

1. Copy the arrays
2. Sort the Arrays
3. Compare the 2

The same? Perfect. And you still have the original.